# Login with Twitter without navigating to Twitter (Login Page) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I am developing an application in ASP.NET. My requirement is providing sign with Twitter into ASP application. Originally Twitter API allows navigating the user to Twitter site and there user needs to enter his own credentials... if the provided values are correct then it will redirected to the callback URL with authorization token and verifier.
But I would like to design a page (in my original application) to prompt the user to enter user credentials (of Twitter) and these values to be sent to Twitter API along with API Keys.
Is it possible? If yes can you please send us the procedure..

Comment: As balexandre said you can't do anything about the redirect as that's how OAuth works. You may want to check out ASP.NET 4.5 / Visual Studio 2012 as the default templates include OAuth support. Great as a reference. 

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is implemented in this way and there is nothing you can do.

OAuth is meant to **not allow the end user set it's own credentials in your website**, but in the provider website (this case Twitter).

You should read more about [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) works as there are many other website using it.